# Error: Compile Error: Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Schema.SObjectField, String at line 8 column 113

Tags: trigger

```
trigger quantity on OpportunityLineItem (after update){
    set<id> lineset= new set<id>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem ql: trigger.new){
      if((trigger.OldMap.get(ql.id).Quantity!= ql.Quantity)){
           lineset.add(ql.opportunityId);
      }
    }
    list<spr__c> sprlist=[select Status__c,spropportunity__c from spr__c  Where spropportunity__c in:lineset && spr__c.Status__c=='approved||draft'];
   if(sprlist != null && sprlist.size()>0){
           for(spr__c s : sprlist){
               s.Status__c = 'obsolute';
           }
           update sprlist;

       } 

    }
```

Comment: Which line is 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some operators you are using are different in SOQL. Change the query to:

```
list<spr__c> sprlist = [
        select Status__c, spropportunity__c
        from spr__c
        where spropportunity__c in :lineset
        and Status__c in ('approved', 'draft')
        ];
```